# What are possible parameters for the boot option in pxelinux

Tags: linux, boot, boot-loader, pxe

Following is the line from `pxelinux` configuration file:

```
append initrd=gparted/0.28.1/initrd.img boot=live config components union=overlay username=user noswap noeject ip= vga=788 fetch=ftp:/
```

Please suggest `live` means in the `boot` directive and what are the other possible configuration options? Cann't find information about it either on google or syslinux wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about `pxelinux` which is a bootloader but you pasted the `append` parameters which is the parameters that are passed to the kernel and initrd.

We can't help without knowing more about the userland (distro ?).

You can have a look to the whole list of kernel command line parameters [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html)

Parameters that are not documented on this page (think about changing kernel version to fit your on URL) are used by initrd or another process in the boot of the system.
This is quite specific to your distro and should be documented by the distro.

Comment: The distro is gparted, thus Debian-based, that means Debian live-boot and live-config parameter applies. Found [here](https://gparted.org/gparted-live-boot-param.php) after your suggestion :) now I am good to continue, thanks!

Comment: Glad i could help !